# how does LZW works on encoding and decoding

Tags: compression

I need Help on how **LZW works**. like how it encodes **data** along with the **dictionary** and how it is decoded back... please I need this for my compression.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example. Imagine you are trying to compress `AAABBC`.

## Encoding

We'll assume that the original dictionary has all the letters A-Z with codes 1-26.

Here are all the iterations of the encoding:

```
i   word    x   word+x  Output  To dictionary
---------------------------------------------
0           A   A       
1   A       A   AA      1       AA: 27
2   A       A   AA      
3   AA      B   AAB     27      AAB: 28
4   B       B   BB      2       BB: 29
5   B       C   BC      2       BC: 30
6               3
```

The output is: `1 27 2 2 3`

## Decoding

We'll assume, again, that the original dictionary has all the letters A-Z with codes 1-26.

```
i   x   element word    Output  To dictionary
---------------------------------------------
0   1   A       A       A   
1   27  AA      A       AA      AA: 27
2   2   B       AA      B       AAB: 28
3   2   B       B       B       BB: 29
4   3   C       B       C       BC: 30
```

Output: `A AA B B C`, which is the original string.

You can play around with it yourself to get a hang of it here:

- [LZW encoding](http://miscalculators.com/lzw-encoding/)
- [LZW decoding](http://miscalculators.com/lzw-decoding/)